# Отображение результата вычислений (Int) в Label Swift 3.0.1

Tags: swift3

```
@IBOutlet weak var countItem: UILabel!
var countItems = 0
countItem.text = String! (countItems)
```

Последняя строчка некорректна. Подскажите пожалуйста решение.

Comment: Мы вам верим...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может так?

```
countItem.text = String(countItems)
```